# asyncio - re-raise exception from a task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using asyncio to do some TCP comms. I have a `Receive()` function that does `read()` in an infinite loop. This runs as a background task using `asyncio.create_task(Receive())`.

Now, if the connection is closed by the peer an exception (or could be any other exception) is raised which I catch in the `Receive()` function. However, I would like to re-raise that exception so the outer code can decide what to do (e.g. re-connect).

Since the exception is raised in a task, I do not know how to retrieve it.

I've tried to create an example of what I mean:

```
import asyncio

async def divide(x):
    try:
        return 1/x
    except Exception as e:
        print("Divide inner exception: ", e)
        raise   # Re-raise so main() can handle it

async def someFn():
    asyncio.create_task(divide(0))  # Exception is never retrieved
    # await divide(0) # This will raise two exceptions - the original in divide() and in main()

async def main():
    try:
        await someFn()
        # Do other things while someFn() runs
    except Exception as e:
        print("main exception: ", e)

asyncio.run(main())
```

How do I get the task exception in `main()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I get the task exception in `main()`?

You can make use of the fact that a task that raises an exception *completes*, and instead of letting the task run in the background, actually await its completion. This requires the code that creates tasks not to retain the task object returned by `create_task()` and either return it to the caller or store it to a shared set of tasks. (Libraries such as [trio](https://github.com/python-trio/trio) don't even allow blindly spawning a background task and instead require every task to be accompanied by a [nursery](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#trio.Nursery) that defines who handles its exceptions).

For example:

```
async def someFn():
    # set up a background task, but also return it to the caller
    t = asyncio.create_task(divide(0))
    return t

async def other_things():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    try:
        task = await someFn()
        # await both the background task and other things, immediately
        # propagating an exception in either
        await asyncio.gather(task, other_things())
    except Exception as e:
        print("main exception: ", e)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, is there no way to get the exception **immediately** in ```main()``` withOUT needing to move the rest of the code to ```other_things()``` and using ```gather()```?

Comment: @SimpleOne Other approaches are possible, but all will require `main()` to cooperate in some way (not necessarily using `gather`). I don't understand your actual constraints are, so I'm afraid I cannot offer more specific help.

Comment: @user4815162342 for what u add await and async for someFn? Its just return task.

Comment: @VladLatish Because I expect that in real code setting up the task would require interacting with coroutines that can suspend and therefore need to be awaited.

Answer (score -1):

Another option would be to use the `add_done_callback` and this allows some flexibility in not having to know beforehand where in code to handle the task (as is required if using `asyncio.gather()` option).

```py
import asyncio

async def divide(x):
    try:
        return 1/x
    except Exception as e:
        print("Divide inner exception: ", e)
        raise   # Re-raise so callback can handle it 
                # (or don't handle exception here and allow callback to manage)

async def someFn():
    task = asyncio.create_task(divide(0))
    task.add_done_callback(task_cb)

def task_cb(task):
    try:
        task.result()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        pass  # Task cancellation should not be logged as an error.
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception raised by task: ', e)

async def main():
    try:
        await someFn()
        # Do other things while someFn() runs
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle the exception in some way
        print("main exception: ", e)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: `await someFn()` does not raise an exception. All your callback does is print the exception. It does not propagate the exception to main.

Comment: I guess my question was not 100% clear: I just wanted to handle the exception generated by the task ("Since the exception is raised in a task, I do not know how to retrieve it."). I thought that meant getting the exception into `main` but, for me, handling in a callback is fine too.